# Encrypt plain text into JWT

Tags: c#, json, jwt

I'm trying to simulate in c# a login to a website through webrequests but I found out that the login is encrypted what I mean by that is that the password field looks more like some JWT token which is encrypted. I found out that in fiddler that the browser browses to a specific URL from openid-connect/certs before authenticating and the response is a JSON key:

```
{
   "keys":[
      {
         "kid":"R4h_SpzKRWeVKgyRJUQ4bS5sfN2YP1_LJm7vN1TT550",
         "kty":"RSA",
         "alg":"RS256",
         "use":"sig",
         "n":"imYGXL5JReUUSKxltPvLjpjjGEmWXPkJVST0u3QOWBcLe9DUz1jmo_N-CmozkIrudHtQAG302o9WiDjEq_lLJ_EgXe4A3bWz07UzlAKHcwRiX88loWll3mhvNy65_j82ZTgP3wsT-sGyVfn6vNTbS0jOf8DzqVdefyCXyPRYBlfRmb2u4TVWvkJLfCzOR4rE7DGPaDNyuGxWG6h0uAOxQYZZGeLKKKHFbn_mzkNp5NGTjdCJPDJfaniL8OCNJlrCXIBGewwxpZUwzT9BAckxkL_dQj233dgvre4WCSklfwQdCTx4DrW6-V3mEQQFSMWM-mKPyvm_mW1bZq6Y3Gm7sw",
         "e":"AQAB",
         "x5c":[
            "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"
         ],
         "x5t":"HQ_vfcioYQgRZFVunOM1_vcu4yo",
         "x5t#S256":"EptqXztLklj3Y0eOliK_IwDuZDjYzaqN5mBcAwoM-Gk"
      }
   ]
}
```

Can somebody point me to the right direction or help me how to encrypt a plain text to a JWT by using these parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a JSON Web Key so see [rfc7517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517) for details.